# How to prevent link opening when I use .click() on a link/button in Cypress?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

React/Typescript

I have a "Download" button which:

- opens a link
- enables another button to continue to the next step

In the Cypress test, I want to click the button in order to enable the other button, however, I do not want to open the link. How can I prevent that?

`cy.get('[data-cy="app-download"]').click();`

I have tried this which I have found somewhere online:
`cy.getByDataCy('desktop-migration-download').invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click();`
Yet, it only opens the link in the same tab. It does not prevent opening it.

Comment: Is there any reason why you dont want to open the link?

Comment: Yes. The expected behaviour is this: The user clicks the link which opens another page in a new tab where the user can download something. Only after clicking the link the flow where the download link was, show a "Next" button so that the user can continue. In the cypress test I want to show the "Next" button but I want to prevent opening the link. If cypress opens the link and then I close the newly opened tab, any further tests will not run because of this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cookies') at <embedded>:2754:201637`.